# window.opener.top.location work with google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Iam using Javascript to call the child page from the parent page. In the child page i have the code like this which calls the parent page url which points to targetURL. I see this particular navigation works for all browsers except google chrome. Is there any specific reason for not working with chrome?
Any alternate ways of doing this for chrome?

```
   window.opener.top.location = targetURL;
   window.close();
```

I found the child page which is supposed to open as pop up ,its getting opened in one more window tab instead of pop up. Not sure if that is the reason.
the code for calling child page is

```
<div id="searchButton"><a href="javascript:thePopup.newWindow('search.html' ,'970',         '620');">Search</a></div>
```

Comment: Are any errors being logged to the Console?

Comment: No errors as such.. i have updated the question with more findings. I guess the child page is not getting opened as pop up from that line which i added ..This is happening only in chrome.